# Jasmine unit test $scope access

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Why am I unable to access my function in my Controller? The code functions like I would expect it too, however, it doesn't seem to want to allow me access to my function that I'm trying to unit test. It should just return a simple bool, but it's getting killed somewhere.

Here's some code:

RTHelper.js

```
describe('Unit: LocationController', function () {
    var $scope, $httpBackend, $location, injector, ctrl, $controller;
    //beforeEach(function () {
    //    angular.module('TDE').controller('LocationController'); //
    //    inject(function ($injector) {
    //        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    //        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    //        //ctrl = $injector.get('$controller')("LocationController", { $scope: $scope });
    //        injector = $injector;
    //        ctrl = $injector.get('$controller');
    //        //scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    //        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    //        $location = $injector.get('$location');
    //    });
    //});

    //both beforeEach methods work(which one is better? I don't know), so things are getting loaded
    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.module('TDE');
        inject(function ($injector) {
            $location = $injector.get('$location');
            $rootscope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootscope.$new();

            $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

            ctrl = function () {
                return $controller('LocationController', {
                    '$scope': $scope
                })
            };
        })
    });
    it("should just be a holder for something for later", function () {
        expect($scope.BoolCondition()).toBeDefined(); //I don't care what it returns as long as it's accessed honestly
    });  
})
```

LocationController.js

```
    angular
    .module('TDE')
    .controller('LocationController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$window', '$document', 'LocationService', 'HeaderFooterService', 'SearchService', 'TranslationService', 'MTDE_CONFIG', 'LocationPartnerAssignmentService', 'ExperimentService', function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $window, $document, $LocationService, $HeaderFooterService, $SearchService, $TranslationService, $MTDE_CONFIG, $LocationPartnerAssignmentService, $ExperimentService) {

    $scope.BoolCondition = function(myCondition){
        if(//blah blah condition test on myCondition)
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How would I go about getting to that BoolCondition? I'm new to this so you can imagine the struggle of writing unit tests after never having done unit testing.  I've also gone through countless examples and I've done some generic tests, so I'm not totally un-versed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not bootstrapping the module under test correctly. You should use angular.mock.module inside the test

You're not instantiating the controller (where's the call to ctrl()?)

Here's the complete working example and the [fiddle that runs it](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/Epshf/):

```
    describe('Unit: LocationController', function () {
    var $scope, $location, ctrl;
    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module('TDE');
        inject(function (_$location_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
            $location = _$location_;
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

            ctrl = _$controller_('LocationController', {
                '$scope': $scope
            })
        });
    });
    it("should just be a holder for something for later", function () {
        expect($scope.BoolCondition()).toBeDefined();
        expect($scope.BoolCondition()).toBeTruthy();
    });
})
```

Comment: Hey Eitan, thanks for the reply, however, I still get a very annoying error. Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/moduler

I know that it's right in the fiddle since I killed it and could see my function, however I can't get there in my code. Do you have any tips on that error? The results I found are rather lacking...

Comment: What is the entire error? Which module is it missing? It can also be related to your runner configuration, review that as well

Comment: The only files that it shows as causing any sort of problems are:
    at file: /www/js/angular/angular.min.js:6:449
    at file: /www/js/angular/angular.min.js:29:279
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at q (file: /www/js/angular/angular.min.js:7:255)
    at e (file: /www/js/angular/angular.min.js:28:427)
    at Object.Yb [as injector](file: /js/angular/angular.min.js:32:462)
    at workFn (file:/js/angular/angular-mocks.js:2101:52)
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (file: /js/angular/angular-mocks.js:2092:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/spec/RTHelper.js:67:9) <--inject is called here

Comment: First of all, you should run unit tests with the debug angular.js version (non-minified) to get readable stack traces, second, where is thee actual name of the missing module?

Comment: Alright, for the first one, where can I find that file? Also, my specRunner loads this file: app.js                                

angular.module('TDE', []);                         
                  
var TDE = angular.module('TDE', ['ux', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'TDE', 'hmTouchEvents', 'infinite-scroll', 'ui.bootstrap']); 

             which is apparently now not loading...so I'm going to get on that